# Bounds on coefficients: univalent maps

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables

Suppose $f(z)=c_1z+c_2z^2+\cdots+c_nz^n$ is a univalent map on the unit disk.

You may assume $c_1=1$. All coefficients are complex.

Is there a sharp bound on the modulus of the last coefficient $c_n$?

How about the other coefficients?

Comment: $|c_n|\le n$ from the Bieberbach conjecture, and it seems you can't say more in general (try $n=2$).

Comment: Your estimate is true for an infinite series, but what we have is a polynomial. Thus, it is reasonable to expect better bounds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is something to say about $c_n$, if not much about the lower order coefficients.

Since $f(z)$ is a *schlicht* function, $f'(z)\neq0$ throughout the disk. That means, each root of the polynomial $f'(z)$ has modulus $\vert z\vert\geq1$. From
$$f'(z)=1+2c_2z+\cdots+nc_nz^{n-1},$$
we know that the product of the roots is $\frac1{nc_n}$ and this quantity must satisfy
$$\frac1{n\vert c_n\vert}\geq1.$$
In other words, $n\vert c_n\vert\leq1$ or $\vert c_n\vert\leq\frac1n$, which is indeed stronger than $\vert c_n\vert\leq n$.

Comment: And since $z-z^n/n$ is univalent, this is sharp.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the other coefficients $c_k$, Branan [1] showed that $(k+1)c_{k+1}=(n-k)\bar c_{n-k}$ is a necessary condition for univalence in $|z|<1$
if $c_1=1$ and $c_n=1/n$.

For univalent polynomials **with real coefficients and such that $c_{n}=1/n$**, Suffridge [2] has proved that the coefficients $c_{k}$ satisfy the inequalities
$$|c_{k}|\leq |C_{k,1}|,
$$
and for univalent polynomials **with real coefficients and such that $c_{n}=-1/n$**, 
$$
|c_{k}|\leq\begin{cases}
|C_{k,1}|\quad(n\text{ even})\\
|C_{k,2}|\quad(n\text{ odd}),
\end{cases}
$$
where
$$C_{k,j}=\frac{n-k+1}{n}\frac{\sin jk\pi/(n+1)}{\sin j\pi/(n+1)},\qquad k=2,\ldots,n,\quad j=1,\ldots,n.$$
For each $n=1,2,\ldots$, and $1\leq j\leq n$, the polynomials
$$P(z)=\sum_{k=1}^n C_{k,j}z^k$$
are univalent in $|z|<1$, from which follows that the above inequalities are sharp.

> [1] D. A. Brannan, Coefficient regions for univalent polynomials of small degree, Mathematika, 14 (1967), 165-169.
>
> [2] T. J. Suffridge,
>   On univalent polynomials. 
>   J. London Math. Soc. 44 (1969), 496-504.

Comment: It's important to mention that the results in the paper are for real coefficients. Also, notice that Fedor already pointed out the "sharp" case in the comment above.